# Forwarding ports with Laravel/Homestead + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I installed MongoDB on an Homestead server. I didn't manage a proper setup of the forwarding ports so that I can manage the DB with a GUI tool like Mongochef.

I've added those lines to the Vagrantfile but it's still not working.

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
...
    # Configure guest services to be accessible on host
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
...
end
```

Have you guys any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port forwarding for homestead should be occurring in your `homestead.yaml` file, not within the `Vagrantfile` in your box location.

Modify ~/.Homestead/homestead.yaml, scroll to the bottom:

```
ports:
    - send: 3000
      to: 3000
    - send: 27017
      to: 27017
```

You don't need to do anything else here as those ports will be forwarded from `host->guest` without the need to do any more configuring. If this still doesn't work, then the issue is not here but elsewhere.

**Note** you need to `homestead reload --provision` for this to take affect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is not solved yet but this will solve a good part of it.

Comment: I made those change but i'm unable to connect with Robomongo / Mongochief :/